# UISplitViewController with multiple Detail View Controller

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

I am making a splitView application and i want different detail view controllers for all i have studies a lot found that use apples MultipleDetailView Controllers but it is not fully adopted so that any one can use it so is there any way to get this done mean different detailViewController for all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

hi Nazia i just found solution From http://kshitizghimire.com.np/uisplitviewcontroller-multipledetailviews-with-navigation-controller/

you can do like:-

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    // Override point for customization after app launch.
        self.splitViewController =[[UISplitViewController alloc]init];
    self.rootViewController=[[RootViewController alloc]init];
    self.detailViewController=[[FirstDetailViewController alloc]init];

    UINavigationController *rootNav=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:rootViewController];
    UINavigationController *detailNav=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:detailViewController];

    self.splitViewController.viewControllers=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:rootNav,detailNav,nil];
    self.splitViewController.delegate=self.detailViewController;

    // Add the split view controller's view to the window and display.
    [window addSubview:self.splitViewController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}

 -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    /*
     When a row is selected, set the detail view controller's detail item to the item associated with the selected row.
     */
    NSUInteger row = indexPath.row;
    [self.appDelegate.splitViewController viewWillDisappear:YES];
    NSMutableArray *viewControllerArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[[self.appDelegate.splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] viewControllers]];
    [viewControllerArray removeLastObject];

    if (row == 0) {
        self.firstDetailViewController=[[[FirstDetailViewController alloc] init]autorelease];
        [viewControllerArray addObject:self.firstDetailViewController];
        self.appDelegate.splitViewController.delegate = self.firstDetailViewController;

    }

    if (row == 1) {
        self.secondDetailViewController=[[[SecondDetailViewController alloc]init]autorelease];
        [viewControllerArray addObject:self.secondDetailViewController];
        self.appDelegate.splitViewController.delegate = self.secondDetailViewController;
    }
    [[self.appDelegate.splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] setViewControllers:viewControllerArray animated:NO];    

    [self.appDelegate.splitViewController viewWillAppear:YES];
    [viewControllerArray release];

 }
```

you can also check this Demo http://kshitizghimire.com.np/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/MultipleDetailViewsWithNavigator.zip

Comment: Both links are down now. Can you please provide another link? @Nitin Gohel

Comment: create two view controllers FirstDetailViewController, SecondDetailViewController which are detail view controller . and crate one tableview controller named RootViewController. The code -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
} will be on RootViewController. Thats all.